# Errors in making predictions using keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, prediction

I am trying to use a neural network to approximate the log-normal distribution pdf (just as an exercise). However, `model.predict()` always returns 1. Here is my code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import lognorm
from tensorflow import keras

mu = 5
sig =1
data = np.linspace(0,600,10000)
labels =lognorm.pdf(data,sig,0,np.exp(mu))

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64,input_shape=(1,),activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001),
          loss='mse',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(data, labels, epochs=1)

# Now test

x = np.random.lognormal(mu, sig, 100)
y =lognorm.pdf(x,sig,0,np.exp(mu))

score = model.evaluate(x, y)
# score = [0.9951245284080505, 0.0]

# Now try prediction

newx = np.linspace(600,1000,50)
newy = model.predict(newx)
score2 = model.evaluate(newx, newy)
# score2 = [0.0, 1.0]
```

`score2` is 0, but it shouldn't be. Would someone help me find where I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last layer is softmax, which tries to take the highest output field and snap it to the value of one, scaling everything else along with it.

Softmax is mostly used for categorization problems, where you want to clearly declare one potential output as "correct".

In this case, you have only one output, which is intending to represent a value between 0 and 1, so I would use probably another sigmoid on the final layer.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I should not use softmax. I (1) changed the last layer's activation to `activation='linear'` (2) scaled the label by 10^8 (originally it was too small), (3) change the metrics to `metrics=['mse']` and then the model works!